# Altium Net has only one pin error

Tags: altium

I keep getting this error again and again and most of the time that is due to a silly mistake. But this time I am unable to find out what wrong I am doing. Please help me to solve this.

[image]

And here is the FET

[image]

Comment: Willing to bet the pin in your FET is the wrong way around, so there is no connection to the wire.

Comment: I've never used it but it seems clear from the error and the gap in the schematic that you have failed to connect the two devices properly. Try dragging R27 and see if the net follows with it or if you leave it behind.

Comment: @Araho Added the mosfet as well.

Comment: hi @Transistor, Yes R27 is connected well. But when I move the FET, nets do not follow (none of the G, D or S) :(

Comment: So what is R27 connected to if the nets don't move with movement of the FET?

Comment: I think its a problem with Altium itself. Now when I removed R27 and connected the Drain to MCU_VCC directly, the error goes away. So this is must be something with the R27, but can't understand what is that :(

Comment: Strange, I removed R27 added back again and this time no error :( Altium's wire / component connections are really bad. It should create something visually so that it can be understood if 2 points are connected well or not ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You built the FET on a slightly different grid than the resistor then the connection wire (on the schematic) for the two parts may be so close but yet do not electrically connect.

Comment: Hi @Steve, you were correct. There was a problem with the MOSFET's schematic, the pins were reversed :( and thus they were not connecting properly..

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem. The pins on the MOSFET were reversed :( I zoomed in and found it..